# Can I change the default size/posizion of `run` in Windows 10/Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-10, gui

The <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> command is quite handy, but is there a way to change the default size or position of its GUI window in Windows 10 or Windows 11, when I call it show up by <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will loop, waiting for a window whose title
is exactly "Run" and will move it to x-coordinate 200 without changing its
y-coordinate. I also tested resizing the dialog, which doesn't seem to
work very well.

The is the script:

```
#persistent

SetTitleMatchMode, 3
SetTimer AutoMove, 500
Return

AutoMove:
    Winwait Run
    Winmove , , , 200
    Return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [WinWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinWait.htm)
- [SetTitleMatchMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SetTitleMatchMode.htm)
- [WinMove](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinMove.htm)

Comment: thx, according to your advice, i manage use ahk with python tk to rewrite a gui can invoke win run, then resize is possible, and tk gui is easier for maintain and upgrade feature than ahk gui. luckly this python gui is less than 100 locs